# NameError: name 'start_prg' is not defined

Tags: python, telebot

Первый раз работаю с библиотекой Telebot и хотел сделать оповещение в определённое время, но при наступлении заданного времени, программа ругается на функцию, не понимаю как её обозначить в строке `t = Timer(secs, start_prg)`

```
import telebot
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")
x = datetime.today()
y = x.replace(day=x.day + 0, hour=20, minute=4, second=0, microsecond=0)

delta_t = y - x
secs = delta_t.seconds + 1

t = Timer(secs, start_prg)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def start_prg(messgae):
    bot.send_message(messgae.from_user.id, "Внимание! Ивент начался!")


t.start()

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Функция должна быть выше в коде, чем обращение к ней. Если быть более точным, определение функции должно быть прочитано интерпретатором раньше, чем ее имя будет как-то использовано (в вашем случае - передано в другую функцию).

Answer (score 0):

Надо не так:

```
>>> t = Timer(1, foo)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

а так:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print('foo')
...
>>> t = Timer(1, foo)
>>> t.start()
foo
```